# NSCollectionView single selection is not working, but multiple selection is fine

Tags: macos, nscollectionview

As title described,
my NSCollectionView is not working when single selection.

MyNSCollectionView is rendered correcttly,

below code shows how I initialize my NSCollectionView:

```
    self.leftBar.dataSource = self
    self.leftBar.delegate = self

    self.leftBar.isSelectable = true
    self.leftBar.allowsEmptySelection = true

    let layout = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

    layout.itemSize = NSSize(width: 200 , height: 50)

    leftBar.collectionViewLayout = layout


    self.contentView.addSubview(leftBar)

    leftBar <- [
        Top(),
        Left(),
        Bottom(),
        Width(200)
    ]
```

Custom NSCollectionViewItem

```
class LeftBarCell: NSCollectionViewItem {

var leftBarView : LeftBarView?

override func loadView() {
    leftBarView = LeftBarView(frame: NSZeroRect)
    view = leftBarView!
}

func setup(title : String){

    leftBarView?.titleTextView.string = title
}
```

}

In LeftBarView

```
class LeftBarView: NSView {

lazy var titleTextView : NSTextView = {

    let titleTextView = NSTextView()

    titleTextView.isEditable = false
    titleTextView.isSelectable = false
    titleTextView.font = NSFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 20)
    return titleTextView
}()

override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frameRect)

    self.setupViews()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}

func setupViews(){
    self.addSubview(titleTextView)

    self.wantsLayer = true
    self.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.lightGray.cgColor

    titleTextView <- Edges()
}
```

}

I tried to play around with

```
    self.leftBar.isSelectable = true
    leftBar.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

and multiple selection is working. 
The `didSelectItemsAt` from `NSCollectionViewDelegate` is triggered

But then when I try with this

```
    self.leftBar.isSelectable = true
```

or

```
    self.leftBar.isSelectable = true
    self.leftBar.allowsEmptySelection = true
```

It is not working when I click on the collectionviewitem,
The `didSelectItemsAt` from `NSCollectionViewDelegate` is not triggered.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. This is because the textview covers the cell, u might need to disable the textview to become passive.

```
extension NSTextView {

 open override func hitTest(_ point: NSPoint) -> NSView? {
    return nil
   }
}
```